# Importar Excel que não possui padrão para SQL SERVER com C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-excel

Estou com o seguinte cenário: tenho uma planilha de Excel que é fornecida por várias empresas privadas. Essa planilha contém dados de previdência.
O problema é o seguinte: possuo colunas que fazem referencia a dados da empresa e colunas que fazem referencia ao participante; o problema é que o nome das colunas que referenciam a empresa são os mesmos nomes que referenciam o participante, sendo que o único ponto que distingue essa separação entre ambos é um agrupamento feito por um header conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: Planilha exemplo]
Preciso inserir no banco de dados sql server mas as planilhas podem vir com a ordem das colunas alteradas, o que dificulta inserir os dados na tabela por posição. Alguém sabe com posso inserir os dados de forma correta no banco sem colocar os valores da empresa no participante e vice-versa?

Comment: A análise da primeira linha do header é suficiente para tratar as colunas de forma correta. É para ser resolvido programando em C# ou em T-SQL?

Comment: Neste caso farei em c#, mas uma solução pelo T-SQL também seria interessante